# Parse XML with Ajax by title

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

Hello to all I have a question. Here I have a code which I parse with Ajax a xml file, but I have a question how I can parse this XML by Title? I need to put all values in array and after that make a loop or how?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { 
    $.ajax({
        url: xml_url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "xml",
        cache: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            $(msg).find('m\\:properties').each(function (id, item) {
                        var eachsection = $("#div").appendTo("#newdiv");
                        var itemId = $(item).find('d\\:' + id).text();
                        var itemTitle = $(item).find('d\\:' + title).text();
                        var itemCategory = $(item).find('d\\:' + category).text(); 
                        var itemContent = $(item).find('d\\:' + content).text();
                         $(eachsection).each(function() {;
                              $(div).find('.q_weblinksprite_med').text(itemTitle);
                              $(div).find(".status").text(itemStatus);
                              $(div).find('.q_rt_rowcell-1-title').text(itemCategory);
                              $(div).find('.q_clipline').html(itemContent);
                       });
            });
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            console.log("Error");
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: hard for anyone to help without seeing sample xml

Comment: What do you mean by "parse by title"?

Comment: In general I resolved the question, thanks for all